# Why does the sky look blue rather than violet?

Tags: visible-light, sun, atmospheric-science, biophysics, vision

Sky looks blue because because our eyes are sensitive to blue colour. But when viewed through a camera why don't we see violet of the sky even though we can see violet colour of other pictures taken from the camera?

Comment: "our eyes are sensitive to blue colour". This statement is independent of whether or not a camera is involved.

Comment: Hi Varsha, I've linked an exact duplicate of your question.

Comment: Apart from the lower sensitivity to violet, (most off-the-shelf) photo and video cameras are built to produce the same response as the human eye to make pictures appear natural. Though, I'm not sure, how large the deviations are in reality.

Answer (score 0):

Camera sensitivity is a common topic. In short they mimic the sensitivity of the  human eye.

Also your statement that we can see violet in pictures of violet objects is not accurate. It refers to violet as a color, not the 'violet wavelengths' of the spectrum. When we see violet objects we do not see 'violet wavelength' light as much as other wavelengths mixing in our eye producing the *violet color*.